# 「見」＋「も」＋「する」 meaning?

Tags: translation, meaning, nuances, learning

I know there is a nuance difference between a regular verb and verb stem + は/も + する but i don't quite know what the nuance difference is.

sentence in question:

> 言いながら、アクアは椅子に腰掛けこちらを**見もせずに**、スナック菓子をぽりぽりと

What i understand from it:

> While saying that (what she said had said previously), aqua, seated in the chair without even looking this way, munched on snacks.

How would the highlighted part be different in nuance if it was just a regular **「見ずに」**? or instead **「見はせずに」**

If my understanding of any other parts of the sentence is wrong, please tell me so that i may correct it.

Comment: Related (or duplicate?): http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21075/9831　・　http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34431/9831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

このすばですか？　私あの作品大好きです。

Your understanding is correct. This 「も」 should be translated to "even" as you did.

> 見*も*せずに == without *even* looking

So its nuance is like "without doing even such an easy act as looking at me", **which includes a slight blame to Aqua**.

If it were simply 「見ずに」 or 「見はせずに」, it would be just describing her action **without mentioning speaker's emotion at all**.

---

This usage of 「も」, used together with negations, emphasizes the negation introduced by 「ず」. ３-イ of [this dictionary entry](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/218351/meaning/m0u/) matches this usage:

> 動詞の連用形や動作性名詞に付き、打消しの語と呼応して、強い否定の意を表す。「思いもよらぬ話」「返事もしない」

Comment: そうです。このすばです。

thank you for the clarifications and the related dictionary link.